# Cannot find module 'chart.js'

Tags: typescript, webpack, chart.js

I have a webapp thats running webpack, typescript and gulp. I want to use chart.js library and I have installed the chart.js npm package. I tried to define chart.js on one of the JS files and I am getting this: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chart.js'`

My JS file looks like this:

```
import Chart = require( "chart.js" );
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/tsd.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**
Noticed that chart.js definitions file doesnt have a proper module declaration. The left is accounting JS library which clearly defines the module and it works. Im guessing this is the issue. How do I use the declared variable or import it into another JS file?
[image]

Comment: require usually requires a *module name*, not a *filename* - the module name might be `chart` but it depends on how your code is configured. Try `import Chart = require("chart");`

Comment: Also you'd better to write your definitions on a `d.ts` file

Comment: I'v used https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped for definitions. And I have used `require('chart')` as well but no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chartjs/chart.d.ts

Comment: Try `import Chart = require( "./chart" );` instead

Comment: you don't need to add the files section in your tsconfig.json file, infact you should only do that if your adding all of your ts files in that section.

Comment: @BanksySan that didnt work either.

Comment: @KeithW. I've read your question more carefully and updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way the typings were defined for chartjs, you don't need to import it. It is in the global space, so you can just use it like this:

```
let myChart = new Chart(new CanvasRenderingContext2D());
```

Of course, you still need to add a reference to chartjs in your page, so that it is available globally.

Answer (score 7):

I believe there is two issues in your setup, the error you're getting is just the first one, after solving that you will need to setup webpack to recognize your dependencies from TypeScript source code.

Considering you have the module and its typings properly installed...

#### 1 - Get tsc to compile your chart test

First, in your `tsconfig.json` you should omit the "files" directive so the compiler reads all relevant files automatically(including the typings). Then just add an entry on "exclude" for each folder that doesn't need to be compiled (e.g "node_modules"). So your tsconfig.json should look something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

As @vintem posted in the answer below, you don't need to `require()` chart.js as a module, its a package initially designed to be consumed from the browser in the old fashioned way, so it will automatically come into the global scope once the lib is loaded.

#### 2 - Configuring webpack to work with tsc

Create a configuration file for your webpack build in the project root named `webpack.config.js` with something like this as content:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

This makes webpack understand dependencies used in your TypeScript code using [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader), you can install it with:

`npm install ts-loader --save-dev`

If your prefer, you can make those configurations [directly in your gulp file](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html#without-webpack-stream).

---

#### UPDATE 1

When you use from global scope, well... you just use it, like in the @vintem's answer below. However you need to remove your attempt of writing the definition by yourself and just make sure a `/// ref` to the downloaded chart definitions is on the file `typings/tsd.d.ts`, otherwise you're overwriting/mixing those definitions and making a big mess... `tsc` you automatically look typings folder and find everything for you.

If you're receiving an error like "cannot find Chart **module**" it probably means you're still trying to import that module somewhere in your code. You need to try to use it directly with `new Chart(...)` and maybe receive an error like "cannot find Chart **class**", but then is a whole different history.

---

Good luck and please give a try in the above procedures and tell me if you have any progress.

Comment: Iv attached a screenshot of the folder structure. Does that help? ChartJS is inside `node_modules` folder

Comment: @KeithW. Yes, thanks. Add your `tsconfig.json` as well please

Comment: Added tsconfig and screenshot of tsd.d.ts

Comment: I did make the tsconfig file changes and the webpack file changes. but its still saying it cant find the "Chart" module. Please look at the "Important" section on my OP. I think thats the issue. Im not sure how to use it when attached to the global scope

Comment: Now I get a runtime error saying Chart is not defined.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and my problem was that I run:

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

in a different file (not the one with the ionic project).
This might be useful for other people having the same issue.

Comment: This answer was already given by user Thomas Verhoeven. Remove answer because it adds nothing.

Comment: This answer was already given by user Thomas Verhoeven. Remove answer because it adds nothing.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this error came because of a missed dependency `@types/chart.js`.
If this is the case for you too, add the dependency by running either:

```
npm i -D @types/chart.js
```

or

```
yarn add -D @types/chart.js
```

This solved the error for me!

Answer (score -2):

So after you do the `npm install chart.js --save`

Just do this in your javascript file

```
import Chart from 'chart.js'
```